# Convert & downsample mpeg to animated gif?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, image, image-processing, imagemagick

I need to resize an mpeg file down to a smaller size (from 720p to 640x480 with letterbox borders) and convert the final product to an animated gif programmatically.  How can this be done most efficiently?

I'm constrained to performing the operation on Heroku so I need to take into consider the size and the mpegs are generally 25 to 45 MB and I'll need to perform the operations relatively quickly.  Ultimately if push comes to shove and I cannot use Heroku for this part of the procedure, then I can explore a standby VPS, but that's only a last resort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For gif conversion you can use [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/)

Some tips how to [use](http://www.wikihow.com/Use-FFmpeg).

It's posible to make letter box and resize videos.